# yaml header for package vignette to retain .md output

Tags: r, yaml, r-markdown, r-package

I have an R package containing vignettes with examples.  The package is on GitHub and checked by Travis.

My vignettes knit fine to .Rmd.  But I have examples whose output I want to show, and that's not present in the .Rmd output.  For instance, in the [dplyr.Rmd vignette](https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/blob/master/vignettes/dplyr.Rmd), there are lots of code chunks but no outputs when viewing in the browser.

My workaround: I've been knitting to .Md, which shows the printed outputs, and then manually saving the .Md files into my repository to share with users.  I'd like this to be automated.

Can I accomplish this with a YAML header?  My goal:

- Generate .Md file for viewing in the browser
- Generate .Rmd file as well
- Pass `devtools::check()` and on Travis-CI

I've tried combinations of `keep_md: yes` and

```
output: 
  md_document: 
    variant: markdown_github
```

etc.